# Equivalent Docker.DotNet AuthConfig class in KubernetesClient for Dotnet application

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, docker-swarm, k3s

I have a `Dokerswarm` application(.Net) which is using [Authconfig](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/f58748616cc5b679b25496926c5688294c94d850/src/Docker.DotNet/Models/AuthConfig.Generated.cs#L6) class for storing information `[username, passord, serveraddress, tokens etc]` for authenticating with the registries. The same application I am trying to write in `Kubernetes` using [KubernetesClient](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/).

Can someone please let me know if there is any equivalent of [Authconfig](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet/blob/f58748616cc5b679b25496926c5688294c94d850/src/Docker.DotNet/Models/AuthConfig.Generated.cs#L6) class in Kubernetes `K8s.Model` client also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The similar class for creating connection to the k8s APIServer endpoint would be the following:

- [KubernetesClientConfiguration](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/d66c914c86c4fe59fbe8ce2acf3261dbbb754894/src/KubernetesClient/KubernetesClientConfiguration.ConfigFile.cs#L17) (in case you have proper KUBECONFIG environment variable set, or at least k8s config on the disk)

More specific classes could be found in the folder:

- [csharp/src/KubernetesClient/KubeConfigModels/](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/tree/master/src/KubernetesClient/KubeConfigModels)

Usage examples could be found here:

- [csharp/examples/](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/tree/master/examples)

I would also recommend to read the following documentation pages:

- [Access Clusters Using the Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/)
- [Configure Access to Multiple Clusters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)